# Remove index.php for multiple applications in Codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have two folders in application for dev/ and live/ sharing the same system.  This is a fresh install.  How do I remove the index.php in the url via htaccess? I've tried the provided code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

However, nothing seems to change.  How do I adjust the htaccess to remove the index.php from the url path.

Thanks!

Comment: See this [guide](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/)

Answer (score 0):

If your installation is not at the root of the domain, you should remove the `/` before `index.php`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no go.  I have a virtual host setup using MAMP so I can hit the project at ci/ in the browser.  I created a page called profile.  I can hit ci/index.php/profile, but I get a 404 at ci/profile.

Comment: @jaysonp - Did you put the `.htaccess` file inside youe `ci` folder?